# How to extend environment variables in github actions with existing ones?

Tags: github, github-actions

A step in a job requires the setting of an environment variable. is something like the code example below possible to achieve with github actions?

Example:

```
- name: Do Something
  env:
      NEW_VAR: $EXISTING_VAR/subdir
      
  run: |
      echo $NEW_VAR
```

I know, that i can directly use the environment variable, but it would be nice to construct new env vars by concatenating old ones.

There is also `${{ env.EXISTING_VAR }}`, but it looks like that this expression is not evaluated.

Comment: You had tried something like that `"$EXISTING_VAR/subdir"` with quotes

Comment: jep. does not work. the old var will not be expanded

Comment: it looks like, that this [isn't possible](https://github.community/t/how-to-use-env-context/16975).

Comment: it looks like, that github actions cannot access the sys env vars from the virtual environment, but only the provided ones. I hope that my assumptions are wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

### Update 2022

The syntax has changed: `::set-env` [has been deprecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/)  and is replaced with [environment files](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files). This means that you can set the new env variable within `run` in one step and **use it in a subsequent step**. The syntax would be:

```
...
- name: Set env variable
  run: |
    echo "NEW_VAR=${{ env.EXISTING_VAR }}/subdir/${{ env.OTHER_EXISTING_VAR }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
- name: Use env variable
  run: |
    echo ${{ env.NEW_VAR }}
...
```

One caveat is that I was unable to set and use a new environment variable within the same step. Here is a non-working example of what I mean

```
...
- name: Set env variable
  run: |
    echo "VAR_FROM_THE_SAME_STEP=${{ env.EXISTING_VAR }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo "NEW_VAR=${{ env.EXISTING_VAR }}/subdir/${{ env.VAR_FROM_THE_SAME_STEP }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
...
```

Resolving `${{ env.VAR_FROM_THE_SAME_STEP }}` will not work in this case, you would need to do it in a subsequent step, which is of course no big deal in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to set env vars.

Try something like that:

```
- name: Set env to qa
  run: |
    echo "::set-env name=ENVIRONMENT::qa"
```

Although this works for me too:

`ECS_DOCKER_COMPOSE: "docker-compose-$ENVIRONMENT.yml"`

I guess that GitHub actions not work with "/".

Have you tried without slash?

Comment: well, you're setting a var called `ENVIRONMENT` to qa, which can also be done with the `env` key for a job, but i was looking for a concatenation :)

Comment: I know that, because of that I wrote "there is another way to set envs", the second example I had setting a concatenation ENV called ECS_DOCKER_COMPOSE, the two examples were in the same GitHub workflow and working pretty well. :)

Comment: sorry, and thank you for your help, but seems not to correctly set the env variable (on my side). do you have a link to the specific example?

Comment: Of course follow the link: (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)